# Combining multiple lists into one in a nested list

Tags: python, list, nested

I want to group some lists into one:
Here is my list:

```
myList=[[20, 'Start', '2008-10-10', 'End', '2008-11-09', 'NG'] ,
        [21, 'Start', '2008-10-10', 'End', '2008-12-15', 'G'], 
        [22, 'Start', '2009-11-23', 'End', '2009-12-10', 'B']]
```

For items that the start date is the same I want to replace them with only one list that keeps the start date and maximum end date among those items with same start and id of maximum end date. For instance, in the example above, ids 20 and 21 have same start date, so I should replace them with one list like this:

```
[21, 'Start', '2008-10-10', 'End', '2008-12-15', 'G']
```

So the general output for this example should be like this:

```
myList=[[21, 'Start', '2008-10-10', 'End', '2008-12-15', 'G'],
        [22, 'Start', '2009-11-23', 'End', '2009-12-10', 'B']]
```

Comment: Have you tried any methods yet to solve this problem?

Comment: Yes, I will put my code here although I know it doesn't work. @enumaris

Comment: Additionally, it seems that in your output you've simply deleted id 20 from your list, the resulting list is just id 21 list with no parts of id 20 list in it. Do you just want to keep the id 21 list?

Comment: Exactly. For items with same start date I want to keep an item with maximum end date. Honestly, I didn't look at this problem with this point of view. ;) @enumaris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
import re
myList=[[20, 'Start', '2008-10-10', 'End', '2008-11-09', 'NG'] ,
    [21, 'Start', '2008-10-10', 'End', '2008-12-15', 'G'], 
    [22, 'Start', '2009-11-23', 'End', '2009-12-10', 'B']]

new_list = [[a, list(b)] for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(myList, key=lambda x:x[2]), key=lambda x:x[2])]
final_result = [max(b, key=lambda x:list(map(int, re.split('\W+', x[-2])))) for _, b in new_list]
```

Output:

```
[[21, 'Start', '2008-10-10', 'End', '2008-12-15', 'G'], [22, 'Start', '2009-11-23', 'End', '2009-12-10', 'B']]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think it should work but sorry I did not notice that the dates are like this:  '2009-01-12 10:00:00.0' . Do you know how I can find max for them? @Ajax1234

Comment: @user9831231 I updated the solution to handle this, but currently, it accounts for the hours/minutes/seconds as well. Thus, a date with the same year/month/day, but with different times will be treated separately. Is this correct behavior?

Comment: Yes, thanks. But get this error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Start'

Comment: @user9831231 Can you post the line of data that is causing that error? Thank you.

Comment: @user9831231 Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

One way may be to try with `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

myDict = defaultdict(list)
for item in myList:
    # key as date or third item in list
    myDict[item[2]].append(item)

# filter from the result of defaultdict
final_lst = [sorted(v, key = lambda k:k[0], reverse=True)[0] for k, v in list(myDict.items())]
print(final_lst)
```

Result:

```
[[21, 'Start', '2008-10-10', 'End', '2008-12-15', 'G'],
 [22, 'Start', '2009-11-23', 'End', '2009-12-10', 'B']]
```